# How to remove number ( item ) from array and show only strings? using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

i got results:

```
   link https://api/v1/3
   link https://api/v1/3/user
   link https://api/v1/3/customer
   link https://api/v1/3/suppliers
```

i am filtering this results and show only

*3, user, customer, suppliers*

but i want to show only

*user, customer, suppliers*

I want to remove 3... in loop this 3 in seconds interation will be 2 or any other number..

My try

```
const result = obj.links.map((o) => o.href.split("/").pop());
```

and

```
const result = obj.links.map((o) => o.href.replace(/.*(?=\/)/, "").slice(1));
```

but in both case i print 3 ...
i want to show only :

***user, customer, suppliers***

Comment: You have to give some criterion through which you wanna remove the element.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` along with a check if the element popped loosely *equals itself cast to a `Number`*.

```js
const links = [{"href": "https://api/v1/3"},{"href": "https://api/v1/3/user"},{"href": "https://api/v1/3/customer"},{  "href": "https://api/v1/3/suppliers"}];

const result = links.reduce((acc, {href: link}) => {
  const last = link.split('/').pop();
  if (!(last == Number(last))) acc.push(last);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You could achieve the same with a `map` followed by a `filter`, but that would have to iterate your array twice.